# declaring a template function with void return taking a typedef

Tags: c++, function-templates

I have looked at most of the related posts but couldn't find a response that related to my specific usage scenario.

The code is as shown below:

```
//classA.h file

#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using std::is_same;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T> class A;
template<typename T>
using array2As = A<T>[2];

template<typename T> 
void doSomething(array2As);

template<typename T>
class A{
  public:
  A(T);
  private:
  friend void doSomething(array2As);
  A()=delete;
  A(const A&)=delete; 
  A& operator=(const A&)=delete;
  T elem;
};

template<typename T>
A<T>::A(T elem){
  static_assert(is_same<T,int>::value || is_same<T,double>::value, "Compilation error: type must be int or double");
  this.elem = elem;
}

template<typename T> void doSomething(array2As a){
  if(is_same<T,int>::value){ auto sz = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);}
  else{auto sz = sizeof(a)/sizeof(double);}
  static_assert(2 == sz, "Compilation error: array must have exactly 2 elements");
 
  for(auto i=0; i<sizeof(a);++i){
   auto T& = a[i];
   cout << T.elem << endl;
 }

 return;
}
```

The above code doesn't compile, but you can see what I intend to do. I wish to create a type definition for an array of two instances of the same template class type, and then use that type definition in the declaration of my function template. The function template itself is supposed to be a friend function of the template class type.

I get the compilation error for the following line of code (the compilation doesn't proceed any further due to `-Wfatal-errors`):

```
template<typename T> void doSomething(array2As);
```

and the error is

```
error: variable or field 'doSomething' declared void
```

Based on this error, I presume the compiler could not correlate the type definition of `arra2As` to type `T`.

So how can make this work?

TIA

P.S:

here is the `main.cpp` code:

```
#include "classA.h"

int main (){
 
 array2As a = {A(5),A(7)};
 doSomething(a);
 array2As b = {A(1.2),A(6.3)};
 doSomething(b);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `friend doSomething<>(array2As);` is simply missing the `void` return type and `array2As` is missing the `<T>` template argument list everywhere.. However, it still won't work. Array types in function parameters have their size stripped and are converted to pointers to the element type. Either use `std::array` instead of pass-by-reference.

Comment: And `sizeof(a)` does not give you the array size... Given that this is a quite basic misuse that doesn't seem to correlate with the level of the rest of the code, maybe there are other issues as well. I haven't checked the code in detail.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for pointing out the omission about void in the friend declaration....however, I don't understand why I should use arra2As<T>, since array2As itself is defined in terms of A<T>?

Comment: @user17732522 agree sizeof() was a mistake...

Comment: `array2As` is itself a template, just like a `A` is. If you want one specialization of it you need to give it template arguments like any other template. Or how do you expect the compiler to know whether you mean `array2As<int>` (i.e. `A<int>[2]`) or `array2As<double>` (i.e. `A<double>[2]`), etc. when you write `array2As`?

Comment: @user17732522 in that case the using declaration just above the line where the compiler throws an error has no effect? Because irrespective of what T becomes at the time of instantiation, the using declaration should make array2As compatible with the specific instance of T...that was my assumption for putting the using declaration in place...

Comment: The using-syntax is an _alias template declaration_. The purpose is to give a specific set of types aliases, in this case you are giving the types `A<X>[2]` the alias `array2As<X>` for each possible type `X`. The `T` in the declaration itself is just a template parameter name in that declaration and has nothing to do with other template parameters that happen to also be named `T`. Whether you use `T` or `U` or anything else doesn't change the meaning of the declaration at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array2As` is a template, so you have to specify its template arguments anywhere that you use it (except in places where the compiler is able to deduce it for you, like in your `main()`).

For instance:

```
template<typename T> void doSomething(array2As);
```

Needs to be:

```
template<typename T> void doSomething(array2As<T>);
```

And:

```
friend doSomething<>(array2As);
```

Needs to be:

```
friend doSomething<T>(array2As<T>);
```

And:

```
template<typename T> void doSomething<T>(array2As a)
```

Needs to be:

```
template<typename T> void doSomething<T>(array2As<T> a)
```

Comment: I was referring to this link https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends before omitting the type T from the friend declaration....